# FCM: Is there a way to subscribe to all topics matching a regex?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a bridge between MQTT messages and Firebase Cloud Messaging, so that every message coming to selected topics from my MQTT broker can be easily and eco-friendly dispatched to Android devices.

The problem is, my MQTT topics are organized like a tree. I'm yet in time to change the topics' organization, though I'd rather not to, if possible.
I'm already transforming my topics to something compatible with FCM,

```
e.g. realm/area/section/id
```

becoming

```
realm~area~section~id
```

The bridge can subscribe to topics like

```
realm/area/section/#
```

and I'd like android devices to subscribe to FCM like this too. Is there a way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no wildcarding for FCM topic names.  Each topic must have a distinct, known name, and the client must subscribe to each named topic individually.

When sending messages from your server, there is a little more flexibility in the ability to [send to multiple topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#build_send_requests), but you still have to provide the name of each topic.